# Collision Detection not accurate in my game

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

Im making a space invaders game using javascript. So let me get to the point, in my update function in the last for loop i said everytime they collide `console.log("collision")` , but what happenes is at first it waits until it gets to the enemies(whitch is good), then when it touches the enemies it logs collision(whitch is again good), but when it goes out far away it still logs collision? Why is that? Its something wrong with my collision function ill tell you that.Thankyou! here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Space Invaders</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  canvas{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
  }
  #backgroundCanvas{
   background-color: black;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="playerCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="enemiesCanvas" width="550" height="600"></canvas>

   <script>
   (function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var game = {};

      game.stars = [];
      game.width = 550;
      game.height = 600;
      game.images = [];

      game.doneImages = 0;
      game.requiredImages = 0;
      game.keys = [];
      game.projectiles = [];
      game.enemies = [];

      game.count = 0;
      game.division = 48;
      game.left = false;
      game.enemySpeed = 3;

      game.fullShootTimer = 10;
      game.shootTimer = game.fullShootTimer;


      game.contextBackground = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas").getContext('2d');

      game.contextPlayer = document.getElementById("playerCanvas").getContext('2d');

      game.contextEnemies = document.getElementById("enemiesCanvas").getContext('2d');

      game.player = {
        x:  game.width / 2 -50,
        y:  game.height - 103,
        width:80,
        height:100,
        speed: 3,
        rendered: false
      }




      $(document).keydown(function(e){
        game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which] = true;

      })
      $(document).keyup(function(e){
       delete game.keys[e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which];

      })

      /*
      up -38
      down-40
      left -37
      right-39
      w-87
      a-65
      s-83
      d-68
      space-32
    */

    function addBullet(){
      game.projectiles.push({
        x:game.player.x,
        y:game.player.y,
        size: 20,
        speed: 3,
        image: 2

      })

    }

      function init(){
        for(i=0; i<600;i++){
          game.stars.push({
            x:Math.floor(Math.random()* game.width),
            y:Math.floor(Math.random()* game.height),
            size: Math.random()*5
          })
        }

        for(y=0;y<5;y++){
          for(x =0;x<5;x++){
             game.enemies.push({
              x: (x*70) + (70*x) + 10,
              y: (y*70) + (10*y) + 40,
              width:70,
              height: 70,
              image:1
             })
          }
        }


        loop();
      }
      function addStars(num){
          for(i=0; i<num;i++){
            game.stars.push({
              x:Math.floor(Math.random()* game.width),
              y:game.height+10,
              size: Math.random()*5
            })
          }

      }
      function update(){
         addStars(1);
         game.count++;

         if(game.shootTimer>0){
           game.shootTimer--;
         }
           for(i in game.stars){
            if(game.stars[i].y <= -5){
                game.stars.splice(i,1);
            }
            game.stars[i].y--;
           }

           if(game.keys[37] || game.keys[65]){
            if(game.player.x>=0){
              game.player.x-=game.player.speed;
              game.player.rendered = false;
            }

           }
          if(game.keys[39] || game.keys[68]){
              if(game.player.x<=500-50){
              game.player.x+=game.player.speed;
              game.player.rendered = false;
            }

           }
           if(game.count % game.division == 0){
            game.left = !game.left;
           }

           for(i in game.enemies){
              if(game.left){

                game.enemies[i].x-=game.enemySpeed;
              }else{
                game.enemies[i].x+=game.enemySpeed;
              }
            }

            for(i in game.projectiles){
                game.projectiles[i].y-=3;
                if(game.projectiles[i]<=-10){
                  game.projectiles.splice(i,1)
                }
            }

            if(game.keys[32] && game.shootTimer<=0){
                addBullet();
                game.shootTimer = game.fullShootTimer
            }

            for(m in game.enemies){
              for(p in game.projectiles){
                  if(collision(game.enemies[m], game.projectiles[p])){
                    console.log("collision")
                  }
              }
            }
        }

      function render(){
         game.contextBackground.clearRect(0,0,game.width,game.height)
         game.contextBackground.fillStyle = "white";
         for(i in game.stars){
            var star = game.stars[i];
            game.contextBackground.fillRect(star.x,star.y,star.size,star.size);
         }
         if(!game.player.rendered){
       game.contextPlayer.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
      game.contextPlayer.drawImage(game.images[0], game.player.x, game.player.y, game.player.width, game.player.height);
      game.player.rendered = true;
         }

         game.contextBackground.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
         game.contextEnemies.clearRect(0, 0, game.width, game.height);
         for(i in game.enemies){
          var enemy = game.enemies[i];
          game.contextEnemies.drawImage(game.images[enemy.image], enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);
         }

         for(i in game.projectiles){
           var proj = game.projectiles[i];
            game.contextEnemies.drawImage(game.images[proj.image], proj.x, proj.y, proj.size, proj.size);

         }
      }

      function loop(){
          requestAnimFrame(function(){
            loop();
        });
        update();
        render();
      }

      function initImages(paths){
        game.requiredImages = paths.length;
          for(i in paths){
              var img = new Image;
              img.src = paths[i];
              game.images[i] = img;
              game.images[i].onload = function(){
                  game.doneImages++;
              }
          }
      }

      function collision(first,second){
        return !(first.x>second.x + second.width||
                  first.x+first.width < second.x||
                 first.y>second.y+second.height||
                  first.y+first.height<second.y);

      }

      function checkImages(){

        if(game.doneImages>=game.requiredImages){
          init();
        }
        else{
          setTimeout(function(){
            checkImages();

          },1)
        }
      }
      game.contextBackground.font = "bold 50px monaco"
      game.contextBackground.fillStyle = "white";
      game.contextBackground.fillText("loading" , game.width/2-100 ,game.height/2-25)
     initImages(["player.gif", "enemy.png", "bullet.jpg"])
      checkImages();
});

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
   })();
   })();

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried to change the loop entirely, rewrote the collision function... so on

Comment: Are you using the browser debugging tools (usually F12) to break on your collision function to determine what's going on?

Comment: Yes a lot, i tried to make a function that make the bullets dispensary when they reach the top but unsucsesfull                                                           for (i in game.projectiles){
              if(game.projectiles[i].y>game.height){
                console.log("Greater Than!")
              }
            }

Comment: Ok so i made it so it dissapears when it goes but when it is obviously not colliding with the enemies it logs collision....  and i have to go to school now so i cant work on this for 2 hours :( Pls help

Comment: Its something wrong with my collision function ill tell you that

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `collision` function. Evaluate each of those 4 checks in the console, and see what is not firing correctly. You could also set up a Unit Test for that function, passing in known values to make sure it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your code in the place where it checks if the bullet should be removed:

```
for(i in game.projectiles){
  game.projectiles[i].y-=3;
  if(game.projectiles[i].y<=-10){   <-- Missing the "y"
    game.projectiles.splice(i,1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple rectangle to rectangle collision detection I use which works fine for me

```
// Just incase you want to create a simple Mathematics object :p

function Mathematics()
{

}

Mathematics.prototype.PointInRect = function(pnt_x, pnt_y, rect_x, rect_y, rect_w, rect_h)
{
    if ( (pnt_x >= rect_x) && (pnt_x <= rect_x + rect_w - 1) )
    {
        if ( (pnt_y >= rect_y) && (pnt_y <= rect_y + rect_h - 1) )
        {return true;}
    }
    return false;
}

Mathematics.prototype.RectToRectCollision = function(rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h,
                             rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h)
{
    // top-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x, rect1_y, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // top-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x + rect1_w - 1, rect1_y, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x + rect1_w - 1, rect1_y + rect1_h - 1, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect1_x, rect1_y + rect1_h - 1, rect2_x, rect2_y, rect2_w, rect2_h) ){return true;}
    // Check to see if rectangle 2 is hit any part of rectanlge 1
    // top-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x, rect2_y, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // top-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x + rect2_w - 1, rect2_y, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-right corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x + rect2_w - 1, rect2_y + rect2_h - 1, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // bottom-left corner
    if ( this.PointInRect(rect2_x, rect2_y + rect2_h - 1, rect1_x, rect1_y, rect1_w, rect1_h) ){return true;}
    // If there is no collision
    return false;
}
```

example call

```
mathematics = new Mathematcis();

if (mathematics.RectToRectCollision(
                bullet.XPos,
                bullet.YPos,
                bullet.Sprite.width,
                bullet.Sprite.height,
                enemy.XPos,
                enemy.YPos,
                enemy.Sprite.width,
                enemy.Sprite.height))
{
    alert("collision");
}
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s6zzmxhz/